# textarea goes disabled always

Tags: html, css

I am developing a php/mysqli private message system.
I am copying this design for my private messages system

> I am not the coder of this code ,I am only modifying it for my needs.

you can see its working here.

http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pres/GgGrQO

Full css and html can be seen on the given link.

**HTML**

```
<div class='title'>
  <div class='title_inner'>
    <h1>
      Funky fresh inbox UI
    </h1>
    <h2>
      Just messing around with some concepts for a UI... and this is what i ended up with! Pure css goodness!
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='container_ui'>
    <div class='container_ui__heading'>
      <div class='header_icon'>
        <img src='http://www.jamiecoulter.co.uk/dev/codepen/mail.png'>
      </div>
      <h1>
        inbox
      </h1>
      <div class='menu_icon'>
        <div class='div'></div>
        <div class='div'></div>
        <div class='div'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input id='message-1' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='message-1' href='#move'>
      <div class='container_ui__item'>
        <div class='face'>
          <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/rem/128.jpg'>
          <div class='color_bar one'>
            <p>Now Reading</p>
            <span>Read</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>
          aspca
        </h2>
        <div class='dot active'></div>
        <h3>subj: thanks, you are amazing</h3>
        <h4>Your generous donation saved 3 million puppies...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='container_ui__expand' id='close'>
        <div class='heading'>
          <div class='heading_head'></div>
          <label for='message-1'>
            x
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class='body'>
          <div class='user'>
            <div class='face'>
              <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/rem/128.jpg'>
            </div>
            <div class='details'>
              <h2>aspca</h2>
              <h3>subj: thanks you are amazing</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='content'>
            <p><b>Email text</b></br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et commodo ipsum, ut rhoncus velit. Nullam placerat, ipsum sed pretium varius, magna metus ullamcorper magna, at porta quam libero ut est. Mauris cursus in magna in fermentum. Integer mollis convallis quam, vel dignissim ligula rutrum in.<br/><br/>Pellentesque ut purus porta, gravida tellus et, consectetur massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque egestas convallis urna. Aenean commodo leo eget felis rhoncus blandit. Nam sed odio sed augue lobortis rutrum non vel est..</p>
            <span>Reply:</span>
            <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='message-2' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='message-2'>
      <div class='container_ui__item'>
        <div class='face'>
          <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/boheme/128.jpg'>
          <div class='color_bar two'>
            <p>Now Reading</p>
            <span>Read</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Nobel prize foundation</h2>
        <div class='dot'></div>
        <h3>subj: Your paper on molecular fusion</h3>
        <h4>We are awarding you the nobel...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='container_ui__expand'>
        <div class='heading two'>
          <div class='heading_head'>
            <label for='message-2'>
              x
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='body'>
          <div class='user'>
            <div class='face'>
              <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/boheme/128.jpg'>
            </div>
            <div class='details'>
              <h2>Nobel prize foundation</h2>
              <h3>subj: Your paper on molecular</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='content'>
            <p><b>Email text</b></br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et commodo ipsum, ut rhoncus velit. Nullam placerat, ipsum sed pretium varius, magna metus ullamcorper magna, at porta quam libero ut est. Mauris cursus in magna in fermentum. Integer mollis convallis quam, vel dignissim ligula rutrum in.<br/><br/>Pellentesque ut purus porta, gravida tellus et, consectetur massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque egestas convallis urna. Aenean commodo leo eget felis rhoncus blandit. Nam sed odio sed augue lobortis rutrum non vel est..</p>
            <span>Reply:</span>
            <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='message-3' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='message-3'>
      <div class='container_ui__item'>
        <div class='face'>
          <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/alexmarin/128.jpg'>
          <div class='color_bar three'>
            <p>Now Reading</p>
            <span>Read</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>megan fox</h2>
        <div class='dot active'></div>
        <h3>subj: i miss you</h3>
        <h4>Where have you been? I've been trying to call you...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='container_ui__expand'>
        <div class='heading three'>
          <div class='heading_head'>
            <label for='message-3'>
              x
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='body'>
          <div class='user'>
            <div class='face'>
              <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/alexmarin/128.jpg'>
            </div>
            <div class='details'>
              <h2>megan fox</h2>
              <h3>subj: i miss you</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='content'>
            <p><b>Email text</b></br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et commodo ipsum, ut rhoncus velit. Nullam placerat, ipsum sed pretium varius, magna metus ullamcorper magna, at porta quam libero ut est. Mauris cursus in magna in fermentum. Integer mollis convallis quam, vel dignissim ligula rutrum in.<br/><br/>Pellentesque ut purus porta, gravida tellus et, consectetur massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque egestas convallis urna. Aenean commodo leo eget felis rhoncus blandit. Nam sed odio sed augue lobortis rutrum non vel est..</p>
            <span>Reply:</span>
            <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='message-4' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='message-4'>
      <div class='container_ui__item'>
        <div class='face'>
          <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg'>
          <div class='color_bar four'>
            <p>Now Reading</p>
            <span>Read</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Linkedin</h2>
        <div class='dot active'></div>
        <h3>subj: Message from bill gates</h3>
        <h4>I want to add you to my personal network...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='container_ui__expand'>
        <div class='heading four'>
          <div class='heading_head'>
            <label for='message-4'>
              x
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='body'>
          <div class='user'>
            <div class='face'>
              <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg'>
            </div>
            <div class='details'>
              <h2>Linkedin</h2>
              <h3>Message from bill gates</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='content'>
            <p><b>Email text</b></br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et commodo ipsum, ut rhoncus velit. Nullam placerat, ipsum sed pretium varius, magna metus ullamcorper magna, at porta quam libero ut est. Mauris cursus in magna in fermentum. Integer mollis convallis quam, vel dignissim ligula rutrum in.<br/><br/>Pellentesque ut purus porta, gravida tellus et, consectetur massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque egestas convallis urna. Aenean commodo leo eget felis rhoncus blandit. Nam sed odio sed augue lobortis rutrum non vel est..</p>
            <span>Reply:</span>
            <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='message-5' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='message-5'>
      <div class='container_ui__item'>
        <div class='face'>
          <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/allisongrayce/128.jpg'>
          <div class='color_bar five'>
            <p>Now Reading</p>
            <span>Read</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Jesse pinkman</h2>
        <div class='dot'></div>
        <h3>subj: Let's get together sometime yo!</h3>
        <h4>Hey, how's it going? You free at all this weekend...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='container_ui__expand'>
        <div class='heading five'>
          <div class='heading_head'>
            <label for='message-5'>
              x
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='body'>
          <div class='user'>
            <div class='face'>
              <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/allisongrayce/128.jpg'>
            </div>
            <div class='details'>
              <h2>Jesse pinkman</h2>
              <h3>subj: Let's get together sometime yo!</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='content'>
            <p><b>Email text</b></br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et commodo ipsum, ut rhoncus velit. Nullam placerat, ipsum sed pretium varius, magna metus ullamcorper magna, at porta quam libero ut est. Mauris cursus in magna in fermentum. Integer mollis convallis quam, vel dignissim ligula rutrum in.<br/><br/>Pellentesque ut purus porta, gravida tellus et, consectetur massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque egestas convallis urna. Aenean commodo leo eget felis rhoncus blandit. Nam sed odio sed augue lobortis rutrum non vel est..</p>
            <span>Reply:</span>
            <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='message-6' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='message-6'>
      <div class='container_ui__item'>
        <div class='face'>
          <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/kolage/128.jpg'>
          <div class='color_bar six'>
            <p>Now Reading</p>
            <span>Read</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>James cameron</h2>
        <div class='dot active'></div>
        <h3>subj: avatar 2</h3>
        <h4>Please consider writing the script...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='container_ui__expand'>
        <div class='heading six'>
          <div class='heading_head'>
            <label for='message-6'>
              x
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='body'>
          <div class='user'>
            <div class='face'>
              <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/kolage/128.jpg'>
            </div>
            <div class='details'>
              <h2>James cameron</h2>
              <h3>subj: avatar 2</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='content'>
            <p><b>Email text</b></br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et commodo ipsum, ut rhoncus velit. Nullam placerat, ipsum sed pretium varius, magna metus ullamcorper magna, at porta quam libero ut est. Mauris cursus in magna in fermentum. Integer mollis convallis quam, vel dignissim ligula rutrum in.<br/><br/>Pellentesque ut purus porta, gravida tellus et, consectetur massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque egestas convallis urna. Aenean commodo leo eget felis rhoncus blandit. Nam sed odio sed augue lobortis rutrum non vel est..</p>
            <span>Reply:</span>
            <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am having two problems that I cant solve by myself

1. `<textarea>` or  any other input fields that i place  always goes
   disabled.
2. Now Reading/Read only displays for first field/message , when
       used with php/mysqli and data is filled dynamically.

I cant see any issues with css or html for these two problems.
Can you guys help me to solve these two problems

Comment: Please shorten the code. We don't need the CSS, only part of the html snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your codepen and think its because of the way its structured. Basically if you look at the DOM, `.container_ui` is in front of the right-side box preventing any user interaction.

You can fix this by bringing it forward using:

```
position:relative;
z-index: <number>;
```

Try right-click on the textarea and click Inspect Element (chrome). It can't the textarea since its blocked by another div.

Comment: 1: you mean here and like this : 2: body .container_ui {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 350px;
B: I have tried it but same result